# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'

Tags: django

I use Django 1.11 and got this error

```
class TenantMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        set_tenant_schema_for_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

I tried to fix that:

```
class TenantMiddleware:
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        set_tenant_schema_for_request(request)
        return response
```

is this a correct equivalent using "new" middleware style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first example is example of new-style middleware, and second one is example of old-style middlewares. If you still want to use `process_response(request, response)` in new-style middlewares you should use `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` class, as a parent class of your middleware class.

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

# old-style middleware usage in new versions of django
class TenantMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        set_tenant_schema_for_request(request)
        return response
```

If you use new-style middlewares,,,

```
# new-style middleware usage and explanation
class TenantMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # implement process_request(request) logic here
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # implement process_response(request, response) logic here
        return response # returns HttpResponse or subclasses here.
```

In new-style middlewares, code before `self.get_response(request)` is same as `process_request(request)` and code after `self.get_response(request)` is same as `process_response(request, response)`.

Hope, it helps you.