# MiddlewareMixin missing required argument: 'get_response' django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Does anyone have any ideas on why I am getting this error? My program was working before and I don't know what I changed to cause it to break.

My main website works but whenever I make this get request to http://10.0.0.233:8000/watcher/form/list I get the error below. I searched my whole project and did not find MiddlewareMixin used anywhere.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('form/list',views.get_all_form_items),
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from ast import literal_eval
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json

import sys
sys.path.append("...Utilities") 

from Utilities import string_math

from . models import form_item_db
from . serializers import form_item_db_serializer
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_all_form_items(request):
    snippets = form_item_db.objects.all()
    serializer = form_item_db_serializer(snippets, many=True)
        
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Error:

```
Django version 4.0, using settings 'backend.settings'
Starting development server at http://10.0.0.233:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Jan/2022 02:11:55] "GET /watcher HTTP/1.1" 200 644
[05/Jan/2022 02:11:55] "GET /static/js/main.1924b030.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Jan/2022 02:11:55] "GET /static/css/main.31d6cfe0.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /watcher/form/list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 493, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 410, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 220, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 373, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\authentication.py", line 126, in authenticate
    self.enforce_csrf(request)
  File "C:\Users\bestg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\authentication.py", line 135, in enforce_csrf
    check = CSRFCheck()
TypeError: MiddlewareMixin.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
```

Comment: Have you changed the version of django or rest framework? Also, what versions of those packages are you using?

Comment: @markwalker_ I was originally using django ~3.0 when I made the project I believe. I upgraded to 4.0 though and did not have any issues for a few days until this happened. What packages should I check?

Comment: Ok DRF supports django 4 so it's likely something else at fault here. Something in your middleware classes doesn't work with the django version you're using. You'll need to find out what that app is to then look for an update or some other solution. Some more info on this new style middleware is here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496132/init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-get-response

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is a fix in DRF package on github since 10.2020: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/7921e9af434f2ccfde6962cf8a1b76331cc77722#diff-25717930a68aebbdb51ee5f4060fb1e756d65ee4e8d96faf8ad614ceced0db05

rest_framework/authentication.py around line 139

```
check = CSRFCheck()
```

is changed to

```
def dummy_get_response(request):  # pragma: no cover
    return None

check = CSRFCheck(dummy_get_response)
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough, thank you so much!! pip install -U djangorestframework fixed my issue! I was literally thinking about going through and setting up my django project again